# Fill li with content depending on database results

Tags: javascript, php, html, fat-free-framework

I'm working with fat free framework and am currently working on a bracket generation for competitions.

What I do is passing multiple competitors (from different "layers") to the view to display them in a tree. The basic styling comes from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/efy/pen/RRRyJW).

Now the problem is, that I don't know every field from beginning on, as the result of the first two competitions decide how the next level looks (quarter finals in that case). The problem is though, that if I don't put the fields there, then the complete layout is destroyed, thats why I put empty `<li>` elements for the layer, where the competitors are not clear so far, just like so:

```
<li class="team-item">&nbsp;</li>
<li class="team-item">&nbsp;</li>
<li class="team-item">&nbsp;</li>
<li class="team-item">&nbsp;</li>
```

Same for semi finals and finals then, just with 2 and 1 `<li>`s then.

Now in some of the cells of quarter/seminfinals I already have something in my database. So for example, if there's 8 competitions in "layer1", then I would have 4 empty fields in "layer2", respectively in the quarter finals. These 4 fields have to be predefined in order to keep the layout. Now maybe I only have 1 or 2 of these fields filled already, because the other competitions are not over yet.

So I have to always predefine the fields like in the code above. Now the question is: How do I either replace one empty `<li>` with the filled one or alternatively, how do I fill the empty `<li>` with information, if provided.

```
<ul class="bracket bracket-2">
      <repeat group="{{ @bracket }}" value="{{ @item }}">
        <check if="{{@item.layer == 2}}">
        <!-- li should be filled with this content, if the condition is true, so if in here -->
        <li class="team-item">{{ @item.Vorname1  }} {{ @item.Name1  }} <a href="/getFighterInformation/{{@item.fighter1ID}}"<i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-trophy"></i></li> 
      <li class="team-item">{{ @item.Vorname2  }} {{ @item.Name2  }} <a href="/getFighterInformation/{{@item.fighter2ID}}"<i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-trophy"></i></li>
  </check>
    </repeat>
  <!-- This should be predefined -->
  <li class="team-item">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="team-item">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="team-item">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="team-item">&nbsp;</li>
  <!-------------------------------->
    </ul>
```

That's an example for layer 2 with 8 competitions in layer 1.

I hope you get what I mean, but its pretty hard to explain...

So summarized, the question is: Is it possible to predefine list elements and then fill or replace them, if an if-condition matches?

EDIT:

This is what I get from database, filled into the bracket variable:

```
array(4){
   [
      0
   ]   => array(15)   {
      [
         "ID"
      ]      => string(1) "1"      [
         "eventID"
      ]      => string(1) "1"      [
         "kategorie"
      ]      => string(4) "FA62"      [
         "ebene"
      ]      => string(1) "3"      [
         "fighter1ID"
      ]      => string(2) "21"      [
         "Vorname1"
      ]      => string(5) "one"      [
         "Name1"
      ]      => string(4) "one"      [
         "Geburtsdatum1"
      ]      => string(10) "1999-04-04"      [
         "fighter1Pos"
      ]      => string(1) "0"      [
         "fighter2ID"
      ]      => string(2) "19"      [
         "Vorname2"
      ]      => string(8) "two"      [
         "Name2"
      ]      => string(4) "two"      [
         "Geburtsdatum2"
      ]      => string(10) "1988-12-11"      [
         "fighter2Pos"
      ]      => string(1) "1"      [
         "result"
      ]      => string(1) "0"
   }   [
      1
   ]   => array(15)   {
      [
         "ID"
      ]      => string(1) "2"      [
         "eventID"
      ]      => string(1) "1"      [
         "kategorie"
      ]      => string(4) "FA62"      [
         "ebene"
      ]      => string(1) "3"      [
         "fighter1ID"
      ]      => string(2) "25"      [
         "Vorname1"
      ]      => string(5) "three"      [
         "Name1"
      ]      => string(4) "three"      [
         "Geburtsdatum1"
      ]      => string(10) "1988-08-18"      [
         "fighter1Pos"
      ]      => string(1) "2"      [
         "fighter2ID"
      ]      => string(2) "24"      [
         "Vorname2"
      ]      => string(5) "four"      [
         "Name2"
      ]      => string(4) "four"      [
         "Geburtsdatum2"
      ]      => string(10) "1985-08-17"      [
         "fighter2Pos"
      ]      => string(1) "3"      [
         "result"
      ]      => string(1) "0"
   }   [
      2
   ]   => array(15)   {
      [
         "ID"
      ]      => string(1) "3"      [
         "eventID"
      ]      => string(1) "1"      [
         "kategorie"
      ]      => string(4) "FA62"      [
         "ebene"
      ]      => string(1) "3"      [
         "fighter1ID"
      ]      => string(2) "23"      [
         "Vorname1"
      ]      => string(5) "five"      [
         "Name1"
      ]      => string(4) "five"      [
         "Geburtsdatum1"
      ]      => string(10) "1966-06-16"      [
         "fighter1Pos"
      ]      => string(1) "4"      [
         "fighter2ID"
      ]      => string(2) "20"      [
         "Vorname2"
      ]      => string(8) "six"      [
         "Name2"
      ]      => string(4) "six"      [
         "Geburtsdatum2"
      ]      => string(10) "1966-03-03"      [
         "fighter2Pos"
      ]      => string(1) "5"      [
         "result"
      ]      => string(1) "0"
   }   [
      3
   ]   => array(15)   {
      [
         "ID"
      ]      => string(1) "4"      [
         "eventID"
      ]      => string(1) "1"      [
         "kategorie"
      ]      => string(4) "FA62"      [
         "ebene"
      ]      => string(1) "3"      [
         "fighter1ID"
      ]      => string(2) "18"      [
         "Vorname1"
      ]      => string(6) "seven"      [
         "Name1"
      ]      => string(4) "seven"      [
         "Geburtsdatum1"
      ]      => string(10) "1985-08-17"      [
         "fighter1Pos"
      ]      => string(1) "6"      [
         "fighter2ID"
      ]      => string(2) "22"      [
         "Vorname2"
      ]      => string(9) "eight"      [
         "Name2"
      ]      => string(4) "eight"      [
         "Geburtsdatum2"
      ]      => string(10) "1995-09-15"      [
         "fighter2Pos"
      ]      => string(1) "7"      [
         "result"
      ]      => string(1) "0"
   }
}
```

One box should contain one fighter only, not two fighters. So each array element represents one fight, containing two fighters (referencable by fighter1ID/fighter2ID, respectively Name1, Name2, etc.). fighter1Pos and fighter2Pos then, together with the value "ebene", which is the layer (3, 2, 1 or 0), determine the position in the bracket, so layer 3 with fighter1Pos 7 would be the last "box" in the layer 3 (counting from 0 - 7).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should better prepare data before passing it to the template.

If your `$brackets` array looks like:

```
$brackets = [
  // first bracket
  1 => [
    [
      'A' => ['name' => 'John', 'id' => 123],
      'B' => ['name' => 'Jim', 'id' => 110],
      'time' => '20:00',
    ],
    [
      'A' => ['name' => 'Mary', 'id' => 141],
      'B' => ['name' => 'Bill', 'id' => 190],
      'time' => '14:00',
    ],
    //etc. (8 competitions)
  ],
  // second bracket
  2 => [
    [
      'A' => ['name' => 'John', 'id' => 123],
      'B' => ['name' => 'Mary', 'id' => 141],
      'time' => '18:00',
    ],
    //etc. (4 competitions)
  ],
  // third bracket
  3 => [
    [
      'A' => ['name' => 'John', 'id' => 123],
      'B' => NULL, // competitor B not known yet
      'time' => '16:00',
    ],
    //etc. (2 competitions)
  ],
  // last bracket (final)
  4 => [
    [
      'A' => NULL, // competitor A not known yet
      'B' => NULL, // competitor B not known yet
      'time' => '20:00',
    ],
  ],
];
```

Then your template would simply look like:

```
<div class="tournament-brackets">
  <repeat group="@brackets" key="@k" value="@competitions">
    <ul class="bracket bracket-{{ @k}}">
      <repeat group="@competitions" value="@competition">
        <li class="team-item">
          <check if="@competition.A">
            <true>
              {{ @competition.A.name }}
              <a href="/getFighterInformation/{{ @competition.A.id }}
            </true>
            <false>
              Unknown competitor
            </false>
          </check>
          <time>{{ @competition.time }}</time>
          <check if="@competition.B">
            <true>
              {{ @competition.B.name }}
              <a href="/getFighterInformation/{{ @competition.B.id }}
            </true>
            <false>
              Unknown competitor
            </false>
          </check>
        </li>
      </repeat>
    </ul>
  </repeat>
```

Comment: this definetely leads me in the right direction, but I would appreciate if you could help me out make it really fit to my case. I just added the exact structure of the array above. Also I described its structure, as in my case, in one "box" (or one `team-item`, to use the right class for it), theres only one fighter instead of two. If you could help me adopt your solution to that situation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: to highlight: I think the biggest difference is what I described (so that every fighter has his own box), but also, that no matter if its finals, half finals or quarter finals or whatever, its always the same, so theres no extra array element for that. Instead, the current layer, respectively if its finals, half finals, etc.. is written in the "ebene" column, as described above in my edit

Comment: If you need `.team-item` twice for each "competition", just duplicate the `<li class="team-item">` block inside the `<repeat group="@competitions" value="@competition">` loop: once for competitor A, once for competitor B.

Comment: yeah but thats not the main issue... As mentioned my array is structured differently, so there's not one element per fight, and also there's not one "parent" element per "layer", but the layer is written in the "ebene" column... Would it be better to change the template to fit that then or to change the brackets array? If I would need to change the brackets array, can you show me how I would change it in order to get it to your format?

Comment: Indeed you need to rework the brackets array. Otherwise, you'd have to write a very complex template to handle it, which would lead to something very difficult to maintain. Just rearrange `$brackets` in your controller, so that if looks like the one I've suggested, and the template will remain simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching the problem in the wrong way: if an element doesn't have any content or meaning, then... the element should be removed!

It makes no sense at all having a long list of empty LI elements; if what you want is that in the layout of the page the list is never shorter that x lines, then you should add something like

```
ul {min-height:10em;}
```

in your style sheet.

Adding elements to the HTML only to achieve a specific layout is never a good idea, and trying to add placeholder elements just to then remove them afterwards is a bad idea, not only for the semantic aspect of your HTML code but also for the responsiveness of your user interface to user commands! :)

Comment: with layout I meant more the strucutre of the tree for the competition, which should always be there, and this is only there, if there are empty elements..

Comment: That's exactly what I meant: if you do have a reason for the tag to be there, then you should structure the tags to show that reason...

What I mean is that if, say, you need to always show the box for the finals, even when you still don't know who's going to the finals, then this means you should generate the finals box in a loop that does NOT depend on the real participants...

What I mean is that if for example you have 16 participants, the you should have a fixed loop that creates 16 boxes, then 8,4,2, then one, and that loop should not depend in any way on the list of participants.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select a list item using javascript and then add text to it.

Take this list:

```
<ul>
<li class="team-item">Result 1</li>
<li class="team-item">Result 2</li>
<li class="team-item">Waiting for Result...</li>
<li class="team-item">Waiting for Result...</li>
</ul>
```

and then add a script, as in the example below:

```js
const resultsList = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
const resultsListItems = resultsList.getElementsByTagName('li');

resultsListItems[2].textContent = 'Result 3';
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="team-item">Result 1</li>
<li class="team-item">Result 2</li>
<li class="team-item">Waiting for Result...</li>
<li class="team-item">Waiting for Result...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the problem is, how do I know when to set a value and when not? Can I just write javascript in between the `check` and it's only executed then? I don't think so... So when do I assign values?

Comment: Yes, data comes from database and is then passed to the view.

Comment: the problem is that the data is fetched in another file, where my routes are, so basically in the controller. The data is then only passed into the view where I access it...

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I appreciate your dilemma. I've never worked with an Model / View / Controller setup. I still work within the Structure / Presentation / Behaviour separation of concerns.